# How test required_if with more than one value

Tags: php, laravel

I am newbie with Laravel and picked up a system to give maintenance.

I have this rule:

```
protected $rules = array(
        'per_vlr_principal_rte' => 'required_if:per_fase_processual,2',
        'per_vlr_juros_rte' => 'required_if:per_fase_processual,2',
        'per_vlr_principal_rdo' => 'required_if:per_fase_processual,1,2',
        'per_vlr_juros_rdo' => 'required_if:per_fase_processual,1,2',
        'per_vlr_principal_perito' => 'required_if:per_fase_processual,2',
        'per_vlr_juros_perito' => 'required_if:per_fase_processual,2',
        'per_vlr_homologado' => 'required_if:per_fase_processual,2',
        'per_qte_rte' => 'required',
        'per_competencias' => 'required',
        'per_qte_laudo' => 'required',
        'per_dt_calculo' => 'required'
    );
```

I'd like to know if the code below is correct:

```
'per_vlr_principal_rdo' => 'required_if:per_fase_processual,1,2',
'per_vlr_juros_rdo' => 'required_if:per_fase_processual,1,2',
```

The validation occurs only when the value is 1.

How to fix it?

Comment: The rules are correct. As the [Laravel documentation](https://laravel.com/docs/4.2/validation#rule-required-if) states: _The under validation (in your case `per_vlr_principal_rdo`) must be present if the field (in your case `per_fase_processual`) is equal to any value (in your case `1` or `2`)_.

Comment: Please post what fields are you passing with the request, to see what data the validator is trying to validate against.

Comment: Works this way:
'per_vlr_principal_rdo'    => 'required_if:per_fase_processual,1|required_if:per_fase_processual,2',